# Code coverage in instanbul doesnt update ts file in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, istanbul

So I have a coverage map wihin the index.html. file. But if I look at the index.html file. I see code that is not current in the component.ts file.

for example I have this component(service):

```
export class CalculatorService {


  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {

  }

  add(n1: number, n2:number) {
    this.logger.log("Addition operation called");



    return n1 + n2;
  }

  subtract(n1: number, n2:number) {
    this.logger.log("Subtraction operation calleded");
    return n1 - n2;
  }


}
```

But then I look at the index.html file of the coverage I see this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {LoggerService} from './logger.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalculatorService {


  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {

  }

  add(n1: number, n2:number) {
    this.logger.log("Addition operation called");
    this.logger.log("Addition operation called");



    return n1 + n2;
  }

  subtract(n1: number, n2:number) {
    this.logger.log("Subtraction operation called");
    return n1 - n2;
  }


}
```

and yes, I saved everything.

So how to update the coverage file with the actual files?

Thank you

Comment: If you're using the Angular CLI, run `ng test --code-coverage` in the terminal for the project. [docs](https://angular.io/cli/test).

Comment: Yes, of course I did that. I see the folder, but it looks if it not go in sync, because when I do a change in the component. I don't see that change in the index.html of the coverage.